# Dependency version issue when installing libgl1-mesa-dev

Tags: apt, opengl

I'm a bit new and will freely admit that I haven't a clue what I'm doing.  I'm trying to install the dev packages for OpenGL.  I have used apt-get to install dependencies in the past and it has always worked a treat.  If I had to hazard a guess, the problem is that it is trying to install libglvnd-dev=1.0.0.2-ubuntu2 when I have libglvnd0=1.0.0.2-ubuntu2.1

Here are some/all of the opengl packages that I have installed:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep libgl

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libgl1/now 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,local]
libgl1-mesa-dri/now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
libgl1-mesa-glx/now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
libglapi-mesa/now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
libgles2/now 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,local]
libglib-object-introspection-perl/bionic,now 0.044-2 amd64 [installed]
libglib-perl/bionic,now 3:1.326-1build1 amd64 [installed]
libglib2.0-0/now 2.56.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libglib2.0-bin/now 2.56.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libglib2.0-data/now 2.56.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 all [installed,local]
libglib2.0-dev/now 2.56.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libglib2.0-dev-bin/now 2.56.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libglu1-mesa/bionic,now 9.0.0-2.1build1 amd64 [installed]
libglvnd0/now 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,local]
libglx-mesa0/now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
libglx0/now 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,local]
```

So if I go:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                             libgl-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgl1-mesa-dev' instead of 'libgl-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libx11-xcb-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install libglvnd-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libglvnd-dev : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libegl1 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libgles2 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libgl1 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libglx0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libopengl0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So if I try specifying the same version of libglvnd-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libglvnd-dev=1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version ‘1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1’ for ‘libglvnd-dev’ was not found
```

If I try to downgrade libglvnd0 to 1.0.0-2ubuntu2, it looks like it's going to break a load of gnome components.

Can anyone suggest some next steps?

Thanks

Joe

(Edit: Code formatting)